# Absolute value of supremums vs Supremum of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753644/inequality-about-absolute-value-of-difference-of-supremums). Let $f,g$ be real continuous bounded functions. Does
$$\lvert \sup_x f(x)-\sup_x g(x)\rvert\leq \sup_x\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert?$$

By visualizing some plots, it makes sense. But how to prove it?

Comment: Well, the link you mention immediately shows that $|\sup_x f(x)- \sup_x g(x)|\leq \sup_{x,y}|f(x)-g(y)|$. Just set $A$ and $B$ to be the image of  $f$ and $g$ respectively.

Comment: @zugzug Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fact is true. To see this, write $|f(x)|=|f(x)-g(x)+g(x)|\leq |f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|$. Taking supremum of both sides, we have
$$
\sup_x |f(x)|\leq\sup_x(|f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|)\leq \sup_x|f(x)-g(x)|+\sup_x|g(x)|
$$
so
$$
\sup_x |f(x)|-\sup_x|g(x)|\leq \sup_x|f(x)-g(x)|.
$$
Repeat the same argument but interchange $f$ and $g$.

**EDIT:** It occurred to me that I only showed  that it's true when $f=|f|$ and $g=|g|$, so when both functions are nonnegative. I wonder if the claim is true when $f$ and $g$ have mixed signs.